# replace a region with whitespace

Tags: vim, replace, region

is there a keystroke to replace a region (series of characters, whatever) with a another character (for example whitespace)? 
I am not searching for `c`, because it deletes the existing characters and lets me enter new ones, which may be less or more characters. I want to replace exactly the deleted characters with another char as with `R`.

For example I have this:

```
one two three four
```

and want to replace it with:

```
one two ----- four
```

If the cursor is on the beginning of `three`, I'd like to enter a keystroke, a region (for a example `w` for end-of-word) and a replacing char (in this case `-`) to let vim replace all characters in that region with the given replacing char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try:

```
ver-
```

to replace selected part with `-`

same, if you want to replace / fill the "region" with space, you do:

`ver`<kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. :-) I knew of `v`, but didn't have the idea of using it with `r`.